# How to set File objects and length property at FileList object where the files are also reflected at FormData object?

Tags: javascript, form-data, fileapi, filelist

It is possible to set `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element to a `FileList` from for example a different `<input type="file">` element `.files` property or `DataTransfer.files` property. See [Make .files settable #2866](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2866), [What happens between uploading a file to an HTML form and submitting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636439/what-happens-between-uploading-a-file-to-an-html-form-and-submitting-it/).

`FileList` object has a `Symbol.iterator` property which we can use to set a `File` object which is iterable, however the `.files` `.length` is still set to `0` and passing a `<form>` having `<input type="file">` set where the `.files` is set using the above approach yields a `File` object having `.size` set to `0`.

How to set the `File` at `FileList` and set `.length` of `FileList` to the number of files set, where the files are set at `FormData()` object?

```js
const input = document.createElement("input");

const form = document.createElement("form");

const [...data] = [
  new File(["a"], "a.txt")
, new File(["b"], "b.txt")
];

input.type = "file";

input.name = "files";

input.multiple = true;
// set `File` objects at `FileList`
input.files[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
   for (const file of data) {
     yield file
   };
};

form.appendChild(input);

const fd = new FormData(form);

for (const file of input.files) {
  console.log(file); // `File` objects set at `data`
}

for (const [key, prop] of fd) {
  // `"files"`, single `File` object having `lastModified` property
  // set to a time greater than last `File` object within `data`
  // at Chromium 61, only `"files"` at Firefox 57
  console.log(key, prop); 
}

console.log(input.files.length); // 0
```

Comment: has been fixed in FF57 see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/57#DOM

Answer (score 111, accepted):

## Edit:

As proven **by OP**, in one of [their gist](https://gist.github.com/guest271314/7eac2c21911f5e40f48933ac78e518bd), there is actually a way to do it...

The [DataTransfer constructor](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#datatransfer) (currently only supported by Blink, [and FF >= 62](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1351193)), should create a mutable FileList <sub>(chrome currently always return a new FileList, but it doesn't really matter for us)</sub>, accessible through the DataTransferItemList.

If I'm not mistaken, this is currently the only specs-wise way to do it, but Firefox had a *bug* in their implementation of the [ClipboardEvent constructor](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-events-and-interfaces), where the same DataTransferItemList was and set to the mode *read/write* which allowed a workaround for FF < 62. <sub>I am not sure of my interpretation of the specs, but I believe it should not be accessible normally).</sub>

So the way *guest271314* found to set arbitrary files on a FileList is as follows:

```js
const dT = new DataTransfer();
dT.items.add(new File(['foo'], 'programmatically_created.txt'));
inp.files = dT.files;
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

This discovery has lead to this [new Proposal](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3269#issuecomment-348902839) to make FileList objects mutable by default, since there is no point anymore to not do it.

However, while this is actually derived from specs behavior, this is more of a loop-hole in the specs and should still be considered an hack. Do not use this in production and instead prefer a simple Array and FormData to control which files are sent to the server.

---

## Previous (outdated) answer

You can't. FileList objects cannot be modified by scripts*.

You can only exchange the FileList of an input to an other FileList, but you can't modify it*.
(*Except for emptying with `input.value = null`).

And you can't either create FileList from scratch, only [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) objects which cannot be created either, and `input[type=file]` will create such objects.

To show you that even when setting an `input[type=file]` FileList to an other input's one no new FileList is created:

```js
var off = inp.cloneNode(); // an offscreen input

inp.onchange = e => {
  console.log('is same before', inp.files === off.files);
  off.files = inp.files; // now 'off' does have the same FileList as 'inp'
  console.log('is same after', inp.files === off.files);
  console.log('offscreen input FileList', off.files);
  console.log('resetting the offscreen input');
  off.value = null;
  console.log('offscreen input FileList', off.files);         
  console.log('inscreen input FileList', inp.files);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

Oh And I almost forgot the FormData part, that I don't really understood to say the truth...

So if I got it ok, all you need is simply `FormData.append()`:

```js
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append("files[]", new Blob(['a']), 'a.txt');
fd.append("files[]", new Blob(['b']), 'b.txt');

for(let pair of fd.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0], pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: @SamuelLiew the new part is still *mainly a hack*. The new specs (as of today only implemented in Blink) allow this, but it isn't really by design, it's more a coincidence. The FF fallback is an abuse of a minor bug in their implementation. So while it's an interesting hack, which will probably [lead to a real API](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3269), for the time being, I do believe the second part of this answer is still needed, moreover, it will still be valid, even with a FileList constructor: You won't be able to modify a FileList, only create new ones.

Comment: @Kaiido Unfortunately, we still cannot create a new `DataTransfer` in Safari (and possibly IE/Edge), correct?

Comment: @mb21 I didn't check recently in Edge, but yes, in my knowledge only Chrome has started the implementation of the DataTransfer constructor, and the FF exploit works only on FF. Btw the bug report you did linked to doesn't really refer to the bug I'm talking about (I did open one so I will add a link to it in an edit), even though it's good to see they're working on it.

Comment: We still can not invoke `DataTransfer` constructor in Safari, IE/Edge

Comment: The DataTransfer constructor now works in Chromium-based Edge.