# Create multiple input type="file" elements with their corresponding value (FileList) according to the main input type="file" (multiple) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileapi

I have this code where I loop unto files from a multiple input file type

```js
$(function(){

$('#main-input').change(function(){
  var files = $('#main-input')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      alert(files[i].name);

  }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="main-input" multiple>
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is clone the main input (#main-input) and gives a value (file) base on the loop files. Any ideas, suggestions please? or is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the requirement is possible. You will need to create a new `FileList` for each `File` object, then set `.files` property of the `<input type="file">` element to the `FileList` populated with the `File` object.

The code at below returns the same results at Chromium 62+ and Firefox 57+, see comments by @Kaiido for evaluations at [Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257041/create-multiple-input-type-file-elements-with-their-corresponding-value-filel/48257086?noredirect=1#comment83498307_48257086) and [Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257041/create-multiple-input-type-file-elements-with-their-corresponding-value-filel/48257086?noredirect=1#comment83498439_48257086).

```js
// FileList.js
class FileList {
  constructor(...items) {
    // flatten rest parameter
    items = [].concat(...items);
    // check if every element of array is an instance of `File`
    if (items.length && !items.every(file => file instanceof File)) {
      throw new TypeError("expected argument to FileList is File or array of File objects");
    }
    // use `ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData` for Firefox, which returns `null` at Chromium
    // we just need the `DataTransfer` instance referenced by `.clipboardData`
    const dt = new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
    // add `File` objects to `DataTransfer` `.items`
    for (let file of items) {
      dt.items.add(file)
    }
    return dt.files;
  }
}

document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.onchange = e => {
  for (let file of e.target.files) {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "file";
    input.files = new FileList(file);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

```js
// FileList.js
function _FileList(items) {
    // flatten rest parameter
    items = [].concat.apply([], [items]);
    // check if every element of array is an instance of `File`
    if (items.length 
        && !items.every(function(file) { 
             return file instanceof File})) {
      throw new TypeError("expected argument to FileList is File or array of File objects");
    }
    // use `ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData` for Firefox, which returns `null` at Chromium
    // we just need the `DataTransfer` instance referenced by `.clipboardData`
    var dt = new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
    // add `File` objects to `DataTransfer` `.items`
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      dt.items.add(items[i])
    }
    return dt.files;
}

document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.onchange = function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "file";
    input.files = new _FileList(e.target.files[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: Is this? I thought you couldn't assign to an input file type? Because of security reasons.

Comment: @Heinrich Yes, it is possible to set `FileList` at `<input type="file">` `.files` property, see [How to set File objects and length property at FileList object where the files are also reflected at FormData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a)

Comment: The things you learn just wandering around StackOverflow, though I have never tried to do this.

Comment: this is es6 right? whats the browser support for this one?

Comment: @JuliverGalleto The code is returns the same results at Chrome/Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: @JuliverGalleto Included a version that does not use `class`, default parameters, rest element, `const`, `let` or `for..of` loop at Answer

Comment: Beware this only works in latest chrome and FF (not tested in Edge, but I don't think it will work there either). In safari and previous versions of any browsers, this will crash, even after transpiled ES6/7 syntax: `new DataTransfer` was an illegal invocation not so long ago, and still is in all browsers but chrome. You know I like your discovery, but I think there should be a warning message in your answer, since it is unfortunately still a *hack*.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you include your evaluations of the code at your answer? Have not used ie in some time, have not tried edge or safari. Would suggest to source the newest versions of FOSS browsers. Updated Answer with link to your comments and disclosure of which browsers the code was tested at.

Comment: @Kaiido Certainly not trying to break the web either way

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for this note. About including a note in *my answer*, do you mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172409/3702797)? If so, I already states in there that only Blink based browsers do support the DataTransfer constructor, and that the new ClipboardEvent thing is an exploit of an FF bug. This tells the same as *won't work in Safari and Edge*. And I know you're not trying to break anything, and you even probably helped to make it [better](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3269#issuecomment-348902839), so kudos.