# Symbols: Well Known Symbols to Change Built-In Behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

To my knowledge, the `Symbol` primitive in JavaScript ES6 is particularly useful for two things:

1. Create unique keys for `Object` properties
2. Override standard built-in JavaScript `Object` methods, properties and operators

   - For example: `Symbol.hasInstance` is called when (before) `instanceof` runs
   - Thus, if we create a custom version of `Symbol.hasInstance`, we could override the behavior of `instanceof`

My somewhat basic question is: Why use a `Symbol` to override these functions? Can't we just override them directly?

For example: Override `String.prototype.match()` instead of `Symbol.match`

Edit: Agree with the commenter that overriding instanceof directly would not work, thus using match() as an example instead.

Comment: How to override `instanceof` directly?

Comment: Agreed, instanceof can't be overridden directly. Thus I used match() as an example instead.

Comment: fwiw, was not able to achieve the setting of aribtrary `File` objects at `<input type="file">` element `.files` property without using `Symbol.iterator` property of the `FileList` object, even though that particular implementation did not fully meet requirement [How to set File objects and length property at FileList object where the files are also reflected at FormData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a)

Comment: Why would you ever want to override an existing prototype method? If the objective is to provide a general override mechanism, requiring every library to override a global function would extremely easy to screw up.

Comment: Another approach to provide a different functionality for a particular globally defined function is to use `class`, which will not override the global native function having the same name. The specific approach depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @loganfsmyth Not sure if I understood you correctly. I would like to change the behavior of say match() or replace() in my own script. Thus, I override it in the script. Due to JavaScript being prototype linked, changing one prototype method in an Object higher up in the prototype chain would affect all the objects that inherit from that changed Object.

Comment: Right. Generally it's considered extremely bad practice to modify objects that you don't conceptually own unless you're explicitly adding a new guaranteed-unique property like a Symbol. It seems like you're promoting that as an alternative to the `Symbol.match` usage. Am I understanding that right? By allowing `Symbol.match` to be added to an object you control, you don't risk affecting anything on a global scale.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks. I guess I am confused about how overriding the behavior of `Symbol.match() {...}` differ from overriding `String.prototype.match() {...}`. If every internal and external JS call of the latter string prototype method first runs `Symbol.match()`, and `Symbol.match()` is prototype linked like any other object in JS, then why would altering the two not have the same outcome?

Comment: Oh, are  you thinking that the `Symbol.match` case is overridden like `Symbol.match = function(){...}`? It's the name of a property, so you do `"".match({ [Symbol.match](){ ... } });` e.g. you own the object that the property lives on, where you don't own the string prototype.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I see now that I do not understand how `well-known symbols` work. In the below MDN article, it seems `Symbol.match` is a property on the `String` object. If we change it to `Symbol.match=false`, it forces `String.prototype.match()` to return `false` on our strings (i.e. a string will never be identified as a regular expression). Will this not apply to the global scope (i.e all places I use `myString.match()`)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/match

Comment: @loganfsmyth A lot of comments here now, perhaps instead, do you have a link where I could read a bit more about what you did here: `"".match({ [Symbol.match](){ ... } });`? Or even better (if you have time), add a full answer clearing up how those well-known symbols can be used. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't quite elaborate enough in your question, but from a bit of inference and the comments, it seems like you are be misunderstanding how well-known symbols are used to interact with existing types. That is causing you to misunderstand how they improve over possible ES5 global overwriting solutions.

It's important to understand that the value of `String.match` is a *symbol*, not a function for matching. It is almost as if someone had done

```
Symbol.match = Symbol("match");
```

at the top of your program to create a new Symbol, and set it as a global property so anyone can access it from anywhere.

This is in contrast with the value of `String.prototype.match` which is the actual function that is used when developers call `"foo".match(...)`.

You seem to be envisioning `String.prototype.match` like

```
String.prototype.match = function(obj) {
  return Symbol.match(obj);
};
```

which is not the case. Looking at a simplified example of the actual implementation may help you understand:

```
String.prototype.match = function(obj) {
  // Any object that has a `Symbol.match` property 
  // will just call that property. This includes every
  // existing RegExp object.
  if (obj != null && obj[Symbol.match] !== undefined) {
    return obj[Symbol.match](this);
  }

  // Otherwise create a new regex to match against
  // match match using that. This is to handle strings, e.g
  // "foo".match("f") 
  const reg = new RegExp(obj);
  return reg[Symbol.match](this);
};
```

and remember, `obj[Symbol.match](this);` is not calling `Symbol.match()`, it is reading a property from `obj` with the *name* `Symbol.match`, and then calling the resulting function.

> Why use a Symbol to override these functions?

Hopefully that example makes the reasoning behind this clearer.

```
var regexp = new RegExp("little");
var result = "a little pattern".match(regexp);
```

is essentially identical to doing

```
var regexp = new RegExp("little");
var result = regexp[Symbol.match]("a little pattern");
```

So why does this matter? Because now when you're designing an API to process text, you aren't limited to doing so with regular expressions. I could make my own whole library as

```
class MyOwnMatcher {
  constructor(word) {
    this.word = word;
  }

  [Symbol.match](haystack) {
    return haystack.indexOf(this.word);
  }
}

var index = "a little pattern".match(new MyOwnMatcher("little"));
// index === 2
```

and most importantly, I'm able to do this without having to change *any* globals. In JS code generally it's considered bad practice to modify globals unless you're polyfilling an officially specced and adopted API. You *could* implement the above like

```
var original = String.prototype.match;
String.prototype.match = function(arg) {
  if (arg instanceof MyOwnMatcher) return this.indexOf(arg);

  return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

but it's extremely ugly, easy to get wrong, and modifies a global object that isn't one that you've defined in your own code.

You can essentially think of well-known symbols as a way to implement an interface defined by a separate piece of code.

Comment: Logan, that is truly helpful, thank you. So, in summary, well-known symbols allow you to create a custom function for one specific object, which will be used by a global built-in object (in place of its own method). The key point is: Only the one object you use the Symbol with, will have the changed behavior. All other uses of say .match() will remain unaffected. Is that the right understanding of its purpose? (PS: Sorry for the late reply, I have been traveling)