# Upload image then update with Multer and Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, mongoose, multer

So I have completed the stage of uploading an image with [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html). Now if I edit an article having that image, I get the correct image. But, what I want to do is that if the image is still the same, don't do anything, else take the new uploaded image.

My problem is that `input[type="file"]` doesn't accept attr `value` to be set by hand. I also read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a) but I don't know if it's relevant to my question or not!

What I get when I submit the edits is `Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`. Yet, I get all other form fields correctly from the request.

I am using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) and [methodOverride](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) for PUT and DELETE [requests](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#routing-methods).

**Multer**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (_req, _file, done) => {
    done(null, path.join(__dirname, './../../public/uploads/'));
  },
  filename: (_req, file, done) => {
    done(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`,
    );
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage
});
```

**For POST request**

```
router.post('/add', authenticate, upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {

    const userId = req.user.id;

    const body = req.body;

    const title = body.title;
    const content = body.content;
    const featured = body.featured;
    const image = req.file.filename;

    const newPost = new Post({
      title,
      content,
      image,
      userId,
      featured
    });

    newPost
      .save()
      .then(post => {
        if (!post) {
          return req.flash('error', 'Unable to add article!!!');
        }
        req.flash('success', 'Added article successfully');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return req.flash('error', 'Unable to add article!!!');
      });

    res.redirect('/posts');
  },
);
```

**For PUT request**

```
router.put(/post/edit/:id', authenticate, upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

const body = req.body;

console.log('body:', body);
console.log('req:', req);

const title = body.title;
const content = body.content;
const featured = body.featured;
const image = req.file.filename;

Post.findOneAndUpdate(id,
  {
    $set: {
      title,
      content,
      featured,
      image
    }
  },
  { new: true }
).then(post => {
    req.flash('success', 'Edits submitted successfully');
    res.redirect('/posts');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return req.flash('error', 'Unable to edit article');
  }); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [`multer.single(fieldname)`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#singlefieldname)

> Accept a single file with the name fieldname. The single file will be stored in req.file.

Because you are doing `upload.single('image')` your `multer` will accept file with the `name` *image* and store it to `req.file.image`. You are however referring it with *filename*. You should therefore replace `req.file.filename` with `req.file.image`.

Also when uploading a new file or editing you would want to check if the `file` exists before processing it with `multer` to avoid *property of undefined* error.

```
if (req.file) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Great explanation for me and works like a charm (Y).

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to check if there is a file attached to the request using `if (req.file)` and modify the database query accordingly.
So your post edit code can go like this:

```
router.put('/post/edit/:id', authenticate, upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    const body = req.body;

    console.log('body:', body);
    console.log('req:', req);


    const title = body.title;
    const content = body.content;
    const featured = body.featured;

    const updates = {
        title,
        content,
        featured
    };

    if (req.file) {
        const image = req.file.filename;
        updates.image = image;
    }


    Post.findOneAndUpdate(id, {
            $set: updates
        }, {
            new: true
        }).then(post => {
            req.flash('success', 'Edits submitted successfully');
            res.redirect('/posts');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return req.flash('error', 'Unable to edit article');
        });
});
```

Comment: I also faced the similar problem and followed your approach. But the req.files is always `undefined` for me in the case of PUT/PATCH request. Can you please help?

Answer (score -1):

```
const multer = require('multer');

 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'public/uploads/')
 },
 filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    var filetype = file.mimetype;
    var fileformate = filetype.split("/")[1];
    callback(null, Date.now() + '.' + fileformate);
 }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is the difference between yours and what I already posted in my question??