# how to remove file from file input(multiple) by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read all the material but couldn't find the answer.
I want remove a file from input file(multiple) by index in jquery .
This is my code.But I could not write a function to delete the index file.
I need the file deletion function by index.

```js
$("#file").change(function () {
 
  
 //Get count of selected files
 var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;

 var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
 var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
 var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
if(countFiles<=10){
 if (extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
     if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

         //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
         for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {

             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 $(image_holder).append("<div class='col-md-2'>  <div class='card bg-dark text-white o-hidden mb-4'> <img class='card-img' src='"+e.target.result+"' style='width:100px;height:100px' alt='Card image'> <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='file_remove('"+i+"')'>remove</button> </div> </div>");
                
             }

             image_holder.show();
             reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
         }

     } else {
         alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
     }
 } else {
     alert("Pls select only images");
 }}
});
```

Comment: Show your code attempt. If you don't show that you at least tried something yourself you might not get an answer.

Comment: @Ivan86 I updated my question.Please look at it again.

Comment: If the client uploads a file to their Browser, it's their Browser, so it will attempt to get that file onchange. You cannot remove it from their list, just deny using it based on conditions.

Comment: @StackSlave I want the client when click on remove button,file remove from input ,I saw a lot of this.

Comment: Even though it's [actually now possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409?r=SearchResults&s=1|76.9897#47172409) to do this in newest browsers, just go the Array way, far easier/stable.

Comment: You can make your own custom file list with an Element like `<ul>`, without attaching the file input to your document using `var fileInput = $("<input type='file' />"); fileInput.change(function(){ for(var i=0,files=this.files,path,file,l=files.length; i<l; i++){ file = files[i]; path = file.value; if(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.')+1).match(/^(pn|jpe?)g$/i)){ yourImage.attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(file)); /* create editable menu */ } });`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to push all of the selected items to an array using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method. Then trying to remove some item using [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method, like this:

```js
$('[type=file]').on('change', function () {
  // after selecting some files, we will push all of them to an array
  var files = Array.from(this.files);
  
  console.log('file count:', files.length);
  
  if (files.length > 1) {
    // trying to delete/remove some item
    files.splice(1,1);
  
    console.log('file count:', files.length);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple />
```

---

Since you update the question, in this case, you can edit to:

```
("#file").change(function () {
    var files = Array.from(this.files);

    // now you can delete/remove some item with the array...

    // inside the loop, you can access the length via
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // code goes here...
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks , but i want remove from input ...this code remove file from input ? Please explain further.

Comment: @ho3ein I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `remove file from input`. My way is just copying all of the selected items to an array and working with it.

Comment: I want the client when click on remove button,file remove from input

Comment: @ho3ein Nope. You can't.

Comment: please see this image .[link](https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/hZH0oB/Capture.PNG)