# How I insert a image data in a input element to generate a FIleList

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed an *image-cropper*, which generates a base64 and after that creates an image file. But I have no idea how to insert image data into an entry to generate a FileList. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand what you need is an input file to pass the event to image-cropper.

PS : the event have the files data.

Example : 
**HTML :**

```
<input id="input-files" type="file" (change)="onImageFileChanged($event)" accept="image/*" />

<image-cropper *ngIf="imageChangedEvent" [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"></image-cropper>
```

TS:

```
imageChangedEvent: any = '';

onImageFileChanged(event: any) {
   this.imageChangedEvent = event;
}
```

Now inside `this.imageChangedEvent` a list of images that you have selected.

If you want to put back your files to input file then try this :

```
const data = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
data.items.add(new File(['foo'], 'image.png'));
  // replace new File(['foo'], 'image.png') with your file
document.getElementById("input-files").files = data.files;
```

Source : [stackoverflow-set-file-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a)

Comment: I already have already do what you told me, but I need to throw the new value generated by the image-cropper to the input. To recover To retrieve later with *NativeElement.files*

Comment: I have added the answer of what you need now.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you help me so much!

Comment: Please note that at the moment this is only supported on Firefox and Chrome (and Edgium).