# Submit multiple files on form as part of axios post

Tags: vue.js, axios

i have created a form to make a submission to an api using axios.
There are 3 other parameters and then the files to submit.

I got it working with one file but what I need to do is be able to have multiple files uploaded and then submit, i tried using the multiple flag but this seems to only allow you to select multiple files in the same folder at once rather than choosing and selecting the files individually.

I don’t want the files sent to the api until the submit button is clicked though.

I thought maybe about using local storage to put the files and then pull to submit at once when the button is clicked?

Comment: I suggest read [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/) how saving things works

Comment: Have you tried to use multiple input fields? Also you might want to checkout vue-croppa component to preview, crop and have more control on events.

Comment: Have you read this one? No localStorage required. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409#47172409

Answer (score 0):

You can use Base64 encode in client side and add the encoded string to your post request and decode from server side.