# FileList, push new image files, access/remove by index

Tags: javascript, html, filelist

This input element allows to take multiple images, for example if i select 2 images i get: FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}. Then if i select again for example 1 image i get another FileList: FileList {0: File, length: 1}. There's a chance to push this new image to the first FileList? And it's possible to remove an image of the FileList by his index? Thanks in advance.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
      console.log(files);

      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {          
        console.log(files[i]);
      }
      // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          continue;
        }

      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
      height: 75px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  <output id="list"></output>
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're claiming that if you `console.log(files.length)`, that it will always output `1`?  I can't reproduce that.  If I select multiple files, then `files.length` is the number of files that I selected.

Comment: FileList isn't always 1. I've uploaded 3 items and it's showing 3.

Comment: i uploaded an image how i see FileList in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the way you can achieve your desired result using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).**

You can change the code to achieve your desired look and functionality.

In summary what the following code does:

1. Creates a new `FormData` instance
2. Accepts files from file input
3. Appends the file to a field named `file-${index}` field of `FormData` created in step 1
4. Creates a `FileReader` instance for each `File`
5. The `FileReader` reads  the file content and returns [data: URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.
6. Creates a `span` element and appends an `img` element to it with the fileContent of step 5 as `src`
7. Attaches the `click` listener to the `span` so when the user clicks an image the corresponding file will be removed from `FormData` of step 1 and the `span` will be removed from `DOM`
8. The `FormData` will be sent to the backend as a request body using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) when the user clicks the `submit files` button using the `sendFiles` function as click handler.

***you can see the list of files attached to `FormData` with their corrponding form field name and original filename under sunbmit button as a `ul` generated using `listFiles` function***

```js
const formData = new FormData();

// to be used for files field names of FormData
let index = 0;

// for listing current files
const listFiles = () => {
  const list = document.createElement("ul");
  Array.from(formData.entries()).forEach((entry) => {
    const item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = entry[0] + ": " + entry[1].name;
    list.appendChild(item);
  });
  document.querySelector("#fileList").innerHTML = list.innerHTML;
};

// for sending files to the backend
const sendFiles = () => {
  fetch("/upload/path", {
    body: formData,
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())  // If the response is in JSON format
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

// for outputting fileReader output and file for FormData
// it needs to be async because of async nature of fileReader onload event so we can keep FormData and FileReader in sync using index
const readFile = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event) => {
      const theFile = event.target;
      return resolve([file, theFile]);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
};

const handleFileSelect = async (event) => {
  var files = event.target.files;
  for (const file of files) {
    if (file.type.match("image.*")) {
      const [fileData, theFile] = await readFile(file);
      const id = `file-${index}`;
      formData.append(id, fileData);
      const span = document.createElement("span");
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = theFile.result;
      img.alt = "Image thumb";
      img.title = escape(fileData.name);
      img.className = "thumb";
      span.appendChild(img);
      // for removing the thumbnail and its linked file from FormData
      span.addEventListener("click", () => {
        formData.delete(id);
        // listing current files appended to FormData after removing this thumbnail
        listFiles();
        span.remove();
      });
      index++;
      document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
    }
  }
  // list files after  adding new file/files
  listFiles();
};

document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
      height: 75px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<br />
<h3>click on images to remove them</h3>
<output id="list"></output>
<br /><br /><br />
<button onclick="sendFiles()">submit Files</button>
<ul id="fileList"></ul>
```

example of [How to upload a file using Fetch](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-upload-files-fetch/) for refrence.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting only a single file 3 times.

To get multiple files you need to select them in a single call from the file-picker.
It will depend on the OS, but on my macOS I can do so by pressing the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key (probably <kbd>ctrl</kbd> on other OSes) while clicking on the items I want to select.

[image: screenshot of the selectpicker with multiple files]
[image: screenshot of the js console result]

Comment: Nice! it's working. Is there any chance to get a FileList by selecting files individually ? Thanks

Comment: @sonEtLumiere you are always getting a FileList, even if it contains a single file. There are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a) to append files to the `input.files`, but wouldn't an Array just be enough for your case?

Comment: Then an Array and a FormData is the way to go.