# Populating an input type tag with a Binary response

Tags: javascript, html, input, binaryfiles

I have a PHP script where the response from the API is a binary file **"resumeBinary"** is the key from the response. So, what I did was to encode it to base64, so that I can easily access its key in in my constructed JSON response data. Here's how the response looks like on the console after fetching it using AJAX:

[image: Response from API with base64 encoded Binary]

What I have done so far is that convert the resumeBinary to its original using atob() function here's how it looks like and its now back to its original binary text strings:

[image: decoded binaryResume]

My question is, is it possible to append the name of the file and the binary value to the HTML input file tag? This is to conform with the request of my client.

The user will authorized the APP then the APP would fetch the users' resume, after receiving the response from the API, I will then append it to the input file type with the other candidate's information. After that they can change that resume file, if they want to or they can just submit the form, I would then post it to another API.

[image: Append Binary File here]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you wan to fill in the [<input type="file"/>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)? These types of inputs allow a user to choose file(s) from **their** device storage and then upload it to a server. Are you trying to send something from one API to another?

Comment: Yes you are right, after a user authorized an API on their behalf it would call the API to fetch its Resume then as part of their step I need to append it to the input tag to pass and post it to another API. I will update my question.

Comment: @Stanislas, I need to follow the flow of steps my client and the API provider told me. The users can they reupload their file if they want to it's just that if they manage to authorize the app it would prefill those data. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible or not (but I don't think so). However, if the data is meant to go from one API to another (without the user seeing, or being able to interact with it), then I don't understand why the data would be send to the client in the first place. Can't one API call the other? If the data must pass via client, then I would consider using a [hidden input field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) instead.

Comment: @Stanislas yes I agree with you, it is a job application form. Where candidates can use their existing SEEK profile and then if they have a CV file or resume PDF on their profile the API would fetch it and then append it to the application form but also have the possibility to change that File if they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you received this response as text it's already too late, the binary data has been corrupted and you won't be able to retrieve it.
You need to [fetch this data as an ArrayBuffer or a Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#receiving_binary_data_using_javascript_typed_arrays). Since you don't show how you made this request, we can't help you much here.

Then you'll be able to convert either of these to a File object that you could pass in a DataTransfer and grab the resulting FileList to the input as demonstrated in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409#47172409) of mine.

However, setting the file like this is still a hack, and it still doesn't work in browsers like Safari and will never work in IE.

Whatever you thought you needed this for, I'm sure there is a better way to do the same, for instance if your goal was to POST this data to your server, then simply use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to make the request the same as with your file input.

```js
const data = new Uint8Array( 128 );
crypto.getRandomValues( data ); // some noisy data

const dT = new DataTransfer();
dT.items.add( new File( [data], "file.ext" ) );
document.querySelector("input").files = dT.files;

const the_form = document.querySelector("form");
const formdata_from_DOM = new FormData( the_form );
new Response( formdata_from_DOM ).text()
  .then( txt => console.log( "from DOM: \n", txt ) );

const formdata_from_JS = new FormData();
formdata_from_JS.append( "the-file", new Blob( [ data ] ), "file.ext" );
new Response( formdata_from_JS ).text()
  .then( txt => console.log( "from JS: \n", txt ) );
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="the-file">
</form>
```

As you can see, both Request's payloads are the same, so better go with the one with better support.

---

And if possible, it would be even better to make the request to the API from your server directly.