# Property 'item' is missing in type 'File[]' but required in type 'FileList'

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I would like to put files into file type input and then in the class fetch and set. The getter looks like this and it works, but I have a problem with the setter because there is an error: "Property 'item' is missing in type 'File []' but required in type 'FileList'". I created an auxiliary interejs to retrieve specific properties.

```
interface IFile{
url: string;
name: string;
}
```

```
class File{
    [x: string]: any;
   
    get files(): File[] {
        const input = (this.querySelector('[name="Input"]') as HTMLInputElement).files;
        return input as any;
    }

    
    set files(value: File[]) {
        (this.querySelector('[name="Input"]') as HTMLInputElement).files = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot name your class `File`. Since `File` is an interface defined by TypeScript. (Not sure if you are trying to override the native type, which is something I wouldn't recommend). You should change `File` to something else, eg. `InputFile`, which would already be helpful.
2. In the line:

```
const input = (this.querySelector('[name="Input"]') as HTMLInputElement).files;
```

The type of `input` variable is `FileList`.

- `FileList` is a superset of the type `File`.
- Hence, you can assign `FileList` type to `File` in your getter.
- However, in your setter, you cannot assign a `File[]` to `FileList`.

Changing the return type of your getter to `FileList` and making corresponding changes in your setter should fix the problem.

Ultimately, your class could look something like:

```
class MyFile {
    [x: string]: any;
   
    get files(): FileList {
        const input = (this.querySelector('[name="Input"]') as HTMLInputElement).files;

        if(input === null) {
          // handle null
          throw Error();
        }

        return input;
    }

    
    set files(value: FileList) {
        (this.querySelector('[name="Input"]') as HTMLInputElement).files = value;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the Documentation, you seem to override the entire FileList thats stored in the HTMLInputElement.files property.
The property expects the new Value to be of a similar Type as FileList. 
But it seems that your Definition of File[] misses the neccessary Property of `item`.

But instead to try to recreate the FileList Type, i would recommend to use the same Types and Features as are native implemented.

I've linked you a reference, where a similar Issues were tackled and there your should find a suitable solution:
[Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a)