# Upload field overwriting file array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm stuck on a problem where i have typescript code that validates a submission form. In this form, an upload field was added where the user can upload multiple files. And a type of visual list was also created for the user to add and remove files. When I click to select the files, and select them all at once in the file explorer, they appear correctly in the array. Now when I add one at a time, only the last file added within the array appears. So I believe that at some point the Array is being overwritten or redefined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv8dL.png)

---

This is the section of code responsible for creating the array and validating the files.

```
const uploadField = document.getElementById('00N1Q00000Tnupu') as HTMLInputElement; //id do campo de upload
const fileListDiv = document.getElementById('fileList') as HTMLDivElement;
const filesArray: File[] = [];

uploadField?.addEventListener('change', function () {
    const files = uploadField.files;

    if (files) {
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const file = files[i];
            const fileName = file.name;
            const fileSizeMB = file.size / (1024 * 1024);
            const allowedFormats = ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf', 'docx', 'xlsx', 'zip'];
            const fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();

            if (fileSizeMB > 10 || !allowedFormats.includes(fileExtension || '')) {
                const erroDiv = document.querySelector('.feedback[data-input="00N1Q00000Tnupu"]');
                erroDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
                erroDiv.classList.add('error');
                const erroDivSpan = document.querySelector('.feedback[data-input="00N1Q00000Tnupu"] span');
                // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                erroDivSpan.innerHTML = 'Please check the uploaded file(s). Make sure that all files are in the allowed formats (jpg, png, pdf, docx, xlsx, zip) and the total size of the files does not exceed 10MB.';
                return;
            }

            filesArray.push(file);

            const fileItem = document.createElement('div');
            fileItem.textContent = fileName;

            const removeButton = document.createElement('i');
            removeButton.classList.add('icon-trash');
            removeButton.style.color = '#a71900';
            removeButton.style.marginLeft = '5px';
            removeButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

                const index = filesArray.indexOf(file);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    filesArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
                fileListDiv.removeChild(fileItem);
            });

            fileItem.appendChild(removeButton);
            fileListDiv.appendChild(fileItem);
        }
    }

    const erroDiv = document.querySelector('.feedback[data-input="00N1Q00000Tnupu"]');
    erroDiv.classList.add('hidden');
    erroDiv.classList.remove('error');
});
```

I had some attempts to store this array separately but without success

Comment: A `File` object is not an `Array`. It is possible to add `File` objects to a `FileList` programmatically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a.